# Ruby, fetch first image from a text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing

Within a Ruby class, I want to parse and fetch the first occurance of an image inside some text that is saved in a database. In particular, I want to collect all `src` attributes.

Will Nokogiri help me? How can I do it?

---

Edit1:

I wrote:

```
// database stuff...
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(my_html)

doc.search('img') do |img_tag|
  puts img_tag
end
```

But I'm not able to collect the image tags.

---

Edit2:

I found the solution:

```
doc.search('img').each do |img_tag|
  puts img_tag.attributes['src']
end
```

Comment: Have you read the Nokogiri docs or examples? It's pretty straight-foward.

Comment: Rather than using `img_tag.attributes['src']`, Nokogiri lets you use `img_tag['src']` to get at the `<img>` node's `'src'` parameter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

str = "some text <img src='/some/path' /> some another text"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(str)
if img = doc.xpath('//img').first
    p img.attr('src')
end
```

### See [live demo here](http://cibox.org/slivu/stackoverflow?lang=ruby&file=ruby-fetch-first-image-from-a-text.rb&run=true)

Comment: Thanks, with doc.xpath I'm now able to collect Image tags.. But how can I do to read the src attribute?

Answer (score 2):

`doc.xpath('//img').first.attr('src').text`

Comment: Can you explain why that works? StackOverflow frowns on short, unexplained answers.

Comment: Seen the first comment by Dave Newton? :)